# RaspberryPi Graphical Application without desktop environment

Tags: xorg, xserver

I want to start my graphical application, immediately after boot, with no desktop environment.

Is this possible and how to do it ?

I am using `Raspberry Pi OS`,

- it boots to the command line
- when I start `XServer`, it runs the desktop manager (`PiXeL`).

I would like to use GUI applications with out a desktop manager.

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't just ask for answers, show what have you done and what are the roadblocks?

Comment: So you have an X11 application that you would like to start without starting X11? I think you can just run the program called `X`.

Comment: If I start XServer, it also launch RaspberryPi desktop... My motive is to launch Xserver without desktop. Please advise further..

Answer (score 0):

Consideration.

in case You need X-server running at client computer, it is not necessary at the server running. to you can use ssh -X to connect and run the application at the server.

Solution

**Step 1: Install**

You need install xorg

```
apt-get Install xorg 
apt-get Install xterm
```

**Setep 2: Create .initrc**
In the home directory create the file .xinitrc and put the commands of the graphical application

```
nano {home_user}/.xinitrc
```

**Setep 3: Run application**

startx is a wrapper for xinit which starts an xserver and one client program. It should do exactly what you want. In the console:

```
startx
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible. However, it will look a bit weird without the windows borders.

#### How to do it:

You can install X windows without installing a desktop (or in your case, [disable the desktop](https://www.xmodulo.com/disable-desktop-gui-raspberry-pi.html)), and run apps under bare X.
Or you can add a minimal window manager.

similar question: [Can I have Graphics on Linux without a desktop manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/493319/can-i-have-graphics-on-linux-without-a-desktop-manager?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

On your Pi, edit the file /etc/rc.local

sudo nano /etc/rc.local
Add commands below the comment, but leave the line exit 0 at the end, then save the file and exit.

For more information you can find [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md)

Comment: which commands and where are these commands... I do not find any commands in your response

Comment: i think this will help you https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12606/run-a-gui-without-the-desktop

Comment: If I launch startx it also start raspberyPi desktop, I want to use startx without desktop.